# Is チョンボ commonly used to mean mistake (outside of conversations about 麻雀), even by people who don't play it?

Tags: usage, colloquial-language

I heard someone say チョンボを犯した in a situation where they could not possibly be talking about 麻雀. I don't know if he plays 麻雀 or not, but it made me wonder, how common is using チョンボ to mean mistake among people who don't play 麻雀?

Comment: This can be a very touchy subject...

Comment: Why would that be?

Comment: 「ぼ」を抜けた時の差別用語のためですか？

Comment: Probably, because it depends on the person. People who like 麻雀 may use it, but people who don't know 麻雀 may not know it.

Comment: That wouldn't warrant calling it a touchy subject...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, チョンボ can be used in non-mahjong situations. As you know, it is originally a mahjong term, but its meaning of "making a mistake" has been carried over to everyday usage. It is even in [dictionaries](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%83%81%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%83%9C).

As for how common, I don't hear it all too often, but enough for me not to automatically assume it's about mahjong just by hearing it.

Note that there are many [mahjong terms that have made it into everyday use](http://majandofu.com/mahjong-vocabulary#p10).　テンパる、メンツ、リーチ、安牌、ワンチャン are ones I still hear used a lot.

Comment: Outside of the Mahjong world, I don't hear/see it used nearly as often as I did in the 80's.  In fact, I rarely hear/see it used in public nowadays.

Comment: ^ そうですね、私も、「チョンボ」って、年配のかたが使ってるのしか聞いたことないです。最初は意味が分からなかった。。

Comment: Well, I feel old now. It is true I only really hear it from my mahjong buddies... The other mahjong terms feel more common, but then again, my experience is skewed since I still play it.